# how can I use accented letters with freetype font?(c++)

Tags: unicode, fonts, char, ascii, freetype

I am making c++ game engine and now I'm on a task that prints some particular letters out with ttf font. Letters like é,à,è and so on. It's for localizing.
Of course there are glyphs for those chars, but if I tried this, only those are broke. I mean, it does not print properly.
I've found some info and they said it can be problem of unicode, ascii, unsigned chars, locale...But every shot I tried failed.

So I want to get your helps. Here's my codes that I think it's related to this issue.
I referenced NEHE's forum.

```
void Text::font_data::SetFont(const char* font_name, unsigned int size)
{
textures = new Texture[128];
this->size = (float)size;

FT_Library library;
if (FT_Init_FreeType(&library))
    throw std::runtime_error("FT_Init_FreeType failed");

FT_Face face = 0;
if (FT_New_Face(library, font_name, 0, &face))
    throw std::runtime_error("FT_New_Face failed (there is probably a problem with your font file)");

FT_Set_Char_Size(face, size << 6, size << 6, 96, 96);
list_base = glGenLists(128);

glGenTextures(128, &(GLuint)textures->texID);
for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
    Make_dlist(face, i, list_base, (GLuint*)&textures->texID);

FT_Done_Face(face);
FT_Done_FreeType(library);
}


void Text::font_data::Clean(void) 
{
glDeleteLists(list_base, 128);
glDeleteTextures(128, (GLuint*)&textures->texID);
delete[] textures;
}

void Text::font_data::Make_dlist(FT_Face face, unsigned char ch, GLuint list_base, GLuint* tex_base)
{
if (FT_Load_Glyph(face, FT_Get_Char_Index(face, ch), FT_LOAD_DEFAULT))
    throw std::runtime_error("FT_Load_Glyph failed");

FT_Glyph glyph;
if (FT_Get_Glyph(face->glyph, &glyph))
    throw std::runtime_error("FT_Load_Glyph failed");

FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap(&glyph, ft_render_mode_normal, 0, 1);
FT_BitmapGlyph bitmap_glyph = (FT_BitmapGlyph)glyph;

FT_Bitmap& bitmap = bitmap_glyph->bitmap;

int width = Next_p2(bitmap.width);
int height = Next_p2(bitmap.rows);

GLubyte* expanded_data = new GLubyte[2 * width * height];

for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
    {
        expanded_data[2 * (i + j*width)] = expanded_data[2 * (i + j*width) + 1]
            = (i >= bitmap.width || j >= bitmap.rows) ?
            0 : bitmap.buffer[i + bitmap.width*j];
    }
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_base[ch]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
    GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, expanded_data);

delete [] expanded_data;

glNewList(list_base + ch, GL_COMPILE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_base[ch]);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(float(bitmap_glyph->left), 0, 0);
glTranslatef(0.f, float(bitmap_glyph->top - bitmap.rows), 0.f);

float x = float(bitmap.width) / float(width);
float y = float(bitmap.rows) / float(height);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(0.f, 0.f); glVertex2f(0.f, float(bitmap.rows));
glTexCoord2d(0.f, y);   glVertex2f(0.f, 0.f);
glTexCoord2d(x, y);     glVertex2f(float(bitmap.width), 0.f);
glTexCoord2d(x, 0.f);   glVertex2f(float(bitmap.width), float(bitmap.rows));
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
glTranslatef(float(face->glyph->advance.x >> 6), 0.f, 0.f);
glEndList();
}

void Text::SetInput(const char *fmt, ...)
{
//const Text::font_data &ft_font

m_font = m_fontInfo.list_base;

m_fontSize = m_fontInfo.size / .63f;

va_list ap;

if (fmt == NULL)
    *m_text = 0;
else {
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vsprintf_s(m_text, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

}

void Text::Draw(float dt)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dt);

m_color = GetSprite()->GetColor();
m_scale = GetSprite()->GetTransform()->GetScale();
m_position = GetSprite()->GetTransform()->GetPosition();

glLoadIdentity();
glColor4f(m_color.R, m_color.G, m_color.B, m_color.A);
glScalef(m_scale.x, m_scale.y, m_scale.z);

//PushScreenCoordMatrix();

const char* start_line = m_text;
vector<string> lines;
const char* c = m_text;

for (; *c; c++)
{
    if (*c == '\n'){
        string line;
        for (const char* n = start_line; n < c; ++n)
            line.append(1, *n);
        lines.push_back(line);
        start_line = c + 1;
    }
}

if (start_line) {
    string line;
    for (const char* n = start_line; n < c; ++n)
        line.append(1, *n);
    lines.push_back(line);
}

glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT | GL_CURRENT_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT | GL_TRANSFORM_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glListBase(m_font);

float modelview_matrix[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview_matrix);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(m_position.x, m_position.y - m_fontSize*i, m_position.z);
    glMultMatrixf(modelview_matrix);

    glCallLists(lines[i].length(), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, lines[i].c_str());

    glPopMatrix();
}

glPopAttrib();
//Pop_projection_matrix();
}
```

Comment: Which font are you using? Because é,à,è and so on work just fine, *if* the font has extended Latin character support

Comment: As I mentioned, the font has those Latin glyphs but it does not work.

Comment: Then first find out whether the problem is you, your font, or freetype: run Freetype's `./freetype2-demos/bin/ftview` on your font and ask it to draw the letter é. If that works, your code is at fault: reduce it until it's a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) that literally just tries to draw the letter é. If after reducing your code still doesn't do what you expect, you have much better, shorter, exact code to go in this question.